# Has anybody used Structure Nav with Transcribe?

Tags: structure, transcribe, multi-language, navigation, eeharbor

I've recently been using Transcribe and wanted to integrate Structure's Nav feature. I have used both separately without issue in the past. But now that I'm bringing them together, I'm having some problems.

I'm using Structure Nav to list some pages (displaying their titles with a custom text field and custom image field) and would like to show the Welsh alternative once the language has been switched. However I don’t seem to be able to do this

```
{exp:structure:nav_advanced start_from="/see-do"}
{exp:ce_img:single src="/assets/images/img.jpg"}
<h3>{root:title}</h3>
<p>{root:page_introduction}</p>
{/exp:structure:nav_advanced}
```

This is my code which works fine for the English side, but is there any way to display the Welsh alternatives once the language is switched?

In the Transcribe documentation, it mentions that there are some tags for Structure but I'm unsure whether this applies to Structure Nav too.

I'm using EE v3.4.4

Can anyone help with this? Has anybody successfully combined the two modules?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it's because you are not starting from the root?
I have it working and have hidden my root (homepage) from the nav (display:none).
I'm actually using nav_basic with ee 4.0.8, Structure 4.3.6 and transcribe 2.2.2

It is working for me.  Here is my opening tag in case it helps you:

`{exp:structure:nav_basic  start_from="/" strict_start_from="yes" show_depth="3"}`

Also, I would recommend double checking what your pages look like in the Welsh tab of structure.  Make sure that they are appearing as they should and that every page has the English and Welsh versions set.